# HTML Table: Edit button trigger Javascript event

Tags: javascript, html, button, triggers, edit

I have a HTML table which I am populating with PHP.

I have

```
<td><a class='Edit_Btn' data-value='".$row["Driver_Reference"]."' onclick='Edit_Btn_Click();' href='#'>Edit</a></td>
```

to build the edit button for each for.

I am trying to avoid using JQuery, but I need to write a Javascript function to get the data-value of the respective edit button that has been pressed, so I can perform the relevant action (in this case it will take me to another page).

Here is what I tried already:

```
function Edit_Btn_Click(Driver_Reference) {
    var Driver_Reference = this.dataValue;

    alert("Edit button pressed! Artist ID: " + Driver_Reference);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your existing function doesn't refers to your element. Change the the HTML and pass current element context to inline click handler i.e. `onclick='Edit_Btn_Click(this);'`

```
 <td><a class='Edit_Btn' data-value='".$row["Driver_Reference"]."' onclick='Edit_Btn_Click(this);' href='#'>Edit</a></td>
```

Then modify your function as

```
function Edit_Btn_Click(elem) {
    var Driver_Reference = elem.dataset.value;

    alert("Edit button pressed! Artist ID: " + Driver_Reference);
}
```

In the above function, You can use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
this.getAttribute('data-value');
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Unfortunately I am getting the error "Scripts.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function"